# I got problems when building AirSim on Mac OSX

Tags: macos

When [building AirSim](https://microsoft.github.io/AirSim/docs/build_linux/#build-airsim-on-linux) on Mac OSX, I run `./setup.sh`, and it does not work.

It goes well on Linux and it's true that AirSim wasn't tested on OSX. I have run `brew update` and `brew doctor` and it doesn't work as well.

Anyone can help me resolve this issue?

```
localhost:AirSim x$ ./setup.sh 
+ set -e
+++ dirname ./setup.sh
++ cd .
++ pwd
+ SCRIPT_DIR=/Users/xuxin/Documents/AirSim
+ pushd /Users/xuxin/Documents/AirSim
+ downloadHighPolySuv=true
+ [[ '' == \-\-\n\o\-\f\u\l\l\-\p\o\l\y\-\c\a\r ]]
++ uname
+ '[' Darwin == Darwin ']'
+ [[ ! -z '' ]]
+ brew tap llvm-hs/homebrew-llvm
==> Tapping llvm-hs/llvm
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/llvm-hs/homebrew-llvm'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 16, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (16/16), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 16 (delta 5), reused 7 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/llvm-hs/homebrew-llvm/Formula/llvm-3.7.rb
Calling fails_with :gcc is disabled! There is no replacement.
Please report this to the llvm-hs/llvm tap:
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/llvm-hs/homebrew-llvm/Formula/llvm-3.7.rb:99

Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/llvm-hs/homebrew-llvm/Formula/llvm-3.8.rb
Calling fails_with :gcc is disabled! There is no replacement.
Please report this to the llvm-hs/llvm tap:
    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/llvm-hs/homebrew-llvm/Formula/llvm-3.8.rb:99

Error: Cannot tap llvm-hs/llvm: invalid syntax in tap!
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if some significant engineering work needs to happen before you can easily build AirSim on macOS, as covered in [issue #2](https://github.com/Microsoft/AirSim/issues/2).

Comment: Thank u, it seems like `brew tap llvm-hs/llvm` went wrong, I run this command separately and got the same error.

Comment: If you're determined to run it, the path of least resistance, short of getting a Windows box, might be to install Bootcamp.

Comment: Thanks for caring. I did some changes in `setup.sh` and `build.sh` and built AirSim on OSX successfully. But I can't run Unreal Engine on OSX and finally I gave up, I will use Linux server to finish my works.